# Undefined behavior for std::vector<bool> resize()

Tags: c++, visual-studio, vector, standards, undefined-behavior

```
#include <vector>
int main()
{
    try {
        std::vector<bool> a;
        a.resize(a.max_size() - 100000000);
    }
    catch (...) {
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I tried to run this program with VS2015 x86, but it crashed in `resize()` with "Access violation". I wonder if there is any undefined behavior? What does the C++ standard say about this?

Comment: _"This value typically reflects the theoretical limit on the size of the container. At runtime, the size of the container may be limited to a value smaller than max_size() by the amount of RAM available._" source: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/max_size  Still I would expect a `std::bad_alloc` exception.

Comment: vector<bool> store 8 value in one byte, for 32bit program, it's about 512MB which is under the address space limit. If there is not enough memory, I should able to catch std::bad_alloc exception. And resize() has "strong exception guarantee", source: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize

Comment: crashed saying what exactly?

Comment: @slawekwin `Unhandled exception at 0x00CC1A0D in test.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x200E5000.`

Comment: FWIW on [ideone](http://ideone.com/AFD44E) it does catch exception. So i'd say it's VS quirk.

Comment: I'd try playing with [`/EH` switches](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1deeycx5.aspx) Windows has their spin on exceptions. (Was looking for link too long to edit previous comment =/)

Comment: Windows uses lazy allocation, if you make a large allocation it may succeed and then crash when you use the space. OS designers think this is a good idea

Comment: @M.M I don't even know if c++ requires for standard lib to throw `bad_alloc` on OOM. It's pretty impossible to enforce it. When you physically can't alloc memory, the thrown object itself might fail to be allocated. Although, I am not 100% sure. Not evaulating windows design, but it might be standard conforming.

Answer (score 1):

`vector<bool>` doesn't always behave like a vector, and it never actually stores bools, but a packed representation of bools that is designed to save
space(bitfields).
`vector<bool>` doesn't satisfy the requirements of an
STL container, you're best off not using it.
`deque<bool>` and bitset are alternatives
data structures that will almost certainly satisfy your need for the capabilities promised
by `vector<bool>`.

Comment: While true, this doesn't answer the question about why the code crashes.